# Why is the master/detail tab missing?

Tags: infopath

I'm trying to build a web-enabled master/detail form with Infopath, so I need to build it with repeating tables bound to my existing data sources. If I open the 'repeating tables properties' dialog box, I don't have a master/data tab.

I have two data connections in the form, for the master table and detail table. I suspect I have to structure this differently in the form to enable this behavior. All the examples I see online are using xml documents as the datasource, which are inherently heirachical.

What's the correct way to structure this?